# Concat if criteria is met and not 0 with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out the best way to setup a concat where only those items that are no 0 are added to the concat.

The logic I need to figure out is
If my direct import column = Yes then concat B-C where the number is greater than 0
otherwise leave the cell blank. I could write out a long set of ElseIF's for each situation but that seems like excessive coding.

I'm not sure that concat is even the best way to handle this so hoping someone has a better idea than mine.
Thanks in advance!

I am currently using the following simple loop

```
With lineWS       
    lr = lineWS.Range("H" & lineWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            If lineWS.Range("AG" & i).Value Like "Yes" Then
               lineWS.Range("S" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCAT(""20'/"",RC[3],""; "",""40'/"",RC[4],""; "",""40HC'/"",RC[5],""; "",""45'/"",RC[6],""; "")"
        Else
        End If
        Next i
End with
```

**Ideal results:**
[image]

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya yeah I think that's a typo on my part. sorry about that. Your formula is really good. but it's just duplicating results from B but this is a great starting point! thank you!

Comment: Posted in answer not for any votes or accepts, just to show that is not duplicating anything as you say.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya When I originally copied your formula I think I missed a comma somewhere. I re did it and it's perfect. Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Could be, we all do mistakes, human after all thanks for your kind words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my proposal to a dynamic array solution using `LAMBDA()` helper function `BYROW()`

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(B3:E7,LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN("; ",1,
 IF(x>0,TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2,"40' HC","40HC'"),"'",-1)&"'"," ")&"/"&x,""))))
```

---

Or, Fill down approach:

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",1,IF(B3:E3>0,
  TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$E$2,"40' HC","40HC'"),"'",-1)&"'"," ")&"/"&B3:E3,""))
```

---

**Capturing all the conditions**<sup>Yes and >0</sup>:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     x, B3:F7,
     y, IF(TAKE(x,,-1)="Yes",DROP(x,,-1),0),
     z, TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2,"40' HC","40HC'"),"'")&"'"," "),
     BYROW(y,LAMBDA(a, TEXTJOIN("; ",1,IF(a>0,z&"/"&a,"")))))
```

---

- Using `LET()` defining variables and making it easy to read.
- `x` is the data array.
- `y` uses an `IF()` return those rows in `Column F` which shows `Yes` else returns `0`. `TAKE()` function to get the direct import col while `DROP()` to exclude the same.
- `z` formats the header as required for concatenating with the required outputted data.
- Using `BYROW()` applies a custom `LAMBDA()` calculations to each row in the array of `y` to check if each value in `y` is `>0` to returns a delimited list after concatenating with respective `z` to return one output per row, and leaving the one don't match the conditions as empty.
- The above formulas spills all at once however, if one likes to apply fill down approach then just change the `x` from `B3:F7` to `B3:F3` and fill down for the rest of the cells.

---

Answer (score 0):

- Formula on cell A3, fill down to A7

```
=IF(F3<>"Yes","",MID(CONCAT(IF(B3>0,"; 20'/"&B3,""),IF(C3>0,"; 40'/"&C3,""),IF(D3>0,"; 40HC'/"&D3,""),IF(E3>0,"; 45'/"&E3,"")),3,9999))
```

[image]

- You will get the VBA code if you recording macro when you apply formulas on column A.

```vb
Sub Macro2()
    Range("A3:A7").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[5]<>""Yes"","""",MID(CONCAT(IF(RC[1]>0,""; 20'/""&RC[1],""""),IF(RC[2]>0,""; 40'/""&RC[2],""""),IF(RC[3]>0,""; 40HC'/""&RC[3],""""),IF(RC[4]>0,""; 45'/""&RC[4],"""")),3,9999))"
End Sub
```